# How do I create an Account from Live Agent Pre-Chat

Tags: community, liveagent

I'm trying to create an account automatically when a user starts a live agent chat. This user is a community user, which means I should already know all of his information including contactId, account number, etc. I have read all of the live agent development guide, but it only shows examples of creating contacts and cases. When I tried to use a similar approach it did not work.
This is what's shown in the development guide:

```
<form method="post" action="#">
<input type='hidden' name='liveagent.prechat:ContactFirstName' value='{!$User.firstname}'/>
<input type='hidden' name='liveagent.prechat:ContactLastName' value='{!$User.lastname}' />
<input type='text' name='liveagent.prechat:CaseSubject' placeholder='Subject'/>
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:Contact" value="FirstName,ContactFirstName;LastName,ContactLastName" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doFind:Contact" value="FirstName,true;LastName,true" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.isExactMatch:Contact" value="FirstName,true;LastName,true" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doCreate:Contact" value="FirstName,true;LastName,true" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.saveToTranscript:Contact" value="ContactId" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.showOnCreate:Contact" value="true" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.linkToEntity:Contact" value="Case,ContactId" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:Case" value="Subject,CaseSubject;Status,CaseStatus" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doCreate:Case" value="Subject,true;Status,true" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

I have tried to use a similar format like this:

```
<input type='hidden' name='liveagent.prechat:AccountName' value='{!$Account.accountname}'/>
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:Account" value="Account,AccountName" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doFind:Account" value="AccountName,true" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.isExactMatch:Account" value="Account,true;" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doCreate:Account" value="AccountName,true" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.saveToTranscript:Account" value="AccountId" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.showOnCreate:Contact" value="true" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.linkToEntity:Contact" value="Case,ContactId" />
```

I'll appreciate all the help!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript Remoting, add a script to your VF page that passes the chat variables to an apex class that does the logic:

See the example below:

VF Page:

```
<input type='hidden' name='liveagent.prechat:AccountName' id="acc"/>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        console.log('Calling Your_Controller...');
        try {
            Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                '{!$RemoteAction.Your_Controller.Your_Controller_Method}',
                function(result, event) {
                    if (event.status) {
                        console.log(result);
                        document.getElementById('acc').value = result.AccountName;
                        var formValid = document.forms["prechatForm"].checkValidity();
                        return formValid;
                    }
                }, {
                    escape: false
                }
                );
        } catch (ex) {
            alert(ex.message);
            console.log(ex);
            return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

The controller:

```
    global without sharing class Your_Controller {

    @remoteAction
    global static boolean Your_Controller_Method() {
        User user = [select Id, ContactId from User where id =: UserInfo.getUserId()];
        // now you have the user so you can find the contact and then the account details
        Account acc = [SELECT id, Name FROM Account......];
        if (acc != null)
            return acc;

    }
}
```

See the documentation:
[JavaScript Remoting for Apex Controllers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting.htm)